# Mysql query limit error

Tags: mysql

I just want to know why "select * from table_name limit 10*10" is not right.

> limit 10*10 error. limit 100 is right.

Is there any mysql document about this?

mysql 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a bit tricky to find the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
>   exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using    integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

Note that the documentation specifies integer constants or parameters in prepared statements in stored programs.

Comment: *"integer constants"* being the key phrase here

Comment: unless you create a prepared statement into them, like in a stored proc, @Phil